# How to add hooks in sequelize Nest.JS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, nestjs, hook

throw new model_not_initialized_error_1.ModelNotInitializedError(this, `Member "${key}" cannot be called.`);
^
Error: Model not initialized: Member "afterCreate" cannot be called. "User" needs to be added to a Sequelize instance.

```
@Table({
  tableName: 'users',
})
export class User extends Model<User> {
@Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  first_name: string;
....
}
```

```
User.afterCreate(async (user, options) => {
  console.log('New User created:');
  console.log(user.first_name);
  console.log(user.email);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As I got it right, you're using `sequelize-typescript`. If yes, then you need to use another approach to define hooks.

```js
import { AfterCreate, Table, Model } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table
export default class User extends Model {
  // ... definition of your columns and other model-related stuff

  @AfterCreate
  static methodName(instance: User) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

You can read more on the `sequelize-typescript`'s [npm package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript#hooks).

Comment: Thats it. Works for me adding hooks @BeforeSave.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution at the end:

```
export class BaseEntity<T> extends Model<T> {
  @CreatedAt
  created_at: Date;
  @UpdatedAt
  updated_at: Date;
  @DeletedAt
  deleted_at: Date;

  @BeforeUpdate
  static async BeforeUpdateHook(instance, options) {
    //TODO do sth
  }

  @AfterCreate
  static async AfterCreateHook(instance, options): Promise<void> {
    //TODO do sth
  }

  @AfterBulkCreate
  static async AfterBulkCreateHook(instances, options): Promise<void> {
    //TODO do sth
  }

  @AfterDestroy
  static async AfterDestroyHook(instance, options): Promise<void> {
    //TODO do sth
  }
}
```

In this way, the required annotations/decorators are bind to sub entities that extend the BaseEntity. So you don't need to add these decorators to all entities that you want to log, that's enough.

In order to trigger these static functions, you should pass some options to CRUD queries that you use.

```
export interface ActivityLogOption {
  hooks?: boolean;
  returning?: boolean;
  individualHooks?: boolean;
}
export const Operation: {[key: string]: Partial<ActivityLogOption>} = {
  BULK_CREATE: {
    hooks: true,
    returning: true,
  },
  CREATE: {
    hooks: true,
    returning: true,
  },
  SAVE: {
    hooks: true,
    returning: true,
  },
  UPDATE: {
    individualHooks: true,
    returning: true,
  },
  DESTROY: {
    hooks: true,
  },
  BULK_DESTROY: {
    individualHooks: true,
  },
};
```

Example:

```
await this.someEntityRepository.destroy({
  where: { id },
  ...Operation.BULK_DESTROY,
});
```

`individualHooks` is used to trigger log each entity that is updated by query.
[This is the detailed explanation of sequelize hooks. check it](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/)

Note: Don't forget to check parameters that are passed by Sequelize. For example: In case of `AfterBulkCreateHook`, the first parameter is an array of instances that you saved.